# Part of the screen on my reader is stuck

Tags: ebook-readers, sony-prs-t1

I have a Sony PRS-T1 where a part of the screen (about 3x6 cm) in the upper left corner seems to be stuck with something previously shown and I cannot clear it:

[image]

I have tried [Sony's instructions](https://us.en.kb.sony.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/31728/c/65,66/p/73878,73940,73941/) for solving similar problems including the hard reset, but it has not solved the issue. Am I completely out of luck here?

Comment: I had the exact same problem with my Kobo Touch, and I couldn't find a way to fix it. Fortunately it was still covered by warranty, so I got it replaced. Hope you have some better luck...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like broken eInk display and I'm afraid that only display replacement can help here.
eInk displays are rather fragile and not only dropping, but something that looks not so dangerous, like putting reader without inflexible cover with paper books in same bag, can mechanically damage display (even if glass is not broken). And display is rather expensive part of reader so if ereader with eInk display is not covered by warranty (good one) replacement may be not cost effective.

Answer (score 5):

Although this might be a broken display as @dsznajder suggest. It could be that there is "just" a problem with the connection between the motherboard and the display. This results in not all pixels, being addressed and on eInk display that means they retain the old value (on an LCD screen the would turn black, or a lack one of the primary colors).

This is not something I would try and figure out and repair yourself. Modern electronics often have ribbon cables that are difficult to remove and reinsert without proper knowledge of and tools for the on-board connector part. Contact Sony on what to do, or find a local electronics repair shop that knows how to handle this kind of electronics.